# How to convert json to table format in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have an external table INV_EXT_TBL( 1 variant column named "VALUE") in Snowflake and it has 6000 rows (each row is json file). The json record has has double quote as its in dynamo_json format.
What is the best approach to parse all the json files and convert it into table format to run sql queries. I have given sample format of just top 3 json files.

```
"{
  ""Item"": {
     ""sortKey"": {
      ""S"": ""DR-1630507718""
    },
    ""vin"": {
      ""S"": ""1FMCU9GD2JUA29""
    }
  }
}"

"{
  ""Item"": {
    ""sortKey"": {
      ""S"": ""affc5dd0875c-1630618108496""
    },
   },
    ""vin"": {
      ""S"": ""SALCH625018""
    }
  }
}"

"{
  ""Item"": {
    ""sortKey"": {
      ""S"": ""affc5dd0875c-1601078453607""
    },
    ""vin"": {
      ""S"": ""KL4CB018677""
    }
  }
}"
```

I created local table and inserted data into it from external table by casting the data type. Is this correct approach OR should i use parse_json function against the json files to store data in local table.

````
insert into DB.SCHEMA.INV_HIST(VIN,SORTKEY)
(SELECT value:Item.vin.S::string AS VIN, value:Item.sortKey.S::string AS SORTKEY FROM INV_EXT_TBL);```
````

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't either using a materialized view over the external table?  Also, does your data actually have double-quotes around each JSON record?  And is the * at the beginning and end just a stackoverflow thing or is that part of your data, as well?

Comment: Mike Walton -  It is exported from dynamoDB so its in dynamo_json format, that's why double quote around each json record. I will explore materialized view on the external table. But the existing approach is not efficient one ?

Comment: It depends on how your data on S3 is being updated.  If you have some other system updating the data and manipulating the various files, then an external table with an MV is the best way to go on Snowflake.  If you are only ever loading new data into Snowflake, then you might want to look into Snowpipe into a table that then has a MV over it that flattens it out.

Comment: Also, I think you might need to use parse_json or cast to variant to get rid of those outer double-quotes when reading your attributes.  I do not understand the situation you are describing with updating and losing data, though.  That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @MikeWalton , Thank you i resolved this with MV approach on external table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by creating a Materialized view by using cast on variant column on External table. This helped to get rid of outer double-quotes and the performance improved multifold. I did not progress with table creation approach.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MATERIALIZED VIEW DB.SCHEMA.MVW_INV_HIST 
AS 
SELECT value:Item.vin.S::string AS VIN, value:Item.sortKey.S::string AS SORTKEY 
FROM DB.SCHEMA.INV_HIST;
```